# Explode string when not between ()

Tags: php, regex, explode, delimiter

I'm trying to `explode` an string by comma's: `,` but only when it's not between parenthesis `(...)`

Here's some code to show what I mean:

```
$string = "K.VisueelNr,IFNULL(P.Partijnaam, 'Leeg gemeld') AS Partijnaam,R.Ras,M.Maat,DATE_FORMAT(KS.Timestamp, '%d-%c-%Y') AS Datum,H.Handelshuis,KS.Actie";

print_r(str_getcsv($string, '()'));

print_r(explode(",", $string));
```

Which will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => K.VisueelNr,IFNULL
    [1] => P.Partijnaam, 'Leeg gemeld') AS Partijnaam,R.Ras,M.Maat,DATE_FORMAT
    [2] => KS.Timestamp, '%d-%c-%Y') AS Datum,H.Handelshuis,KS.Actie
)
Array
(
    [0] => K.VisueelNr
    [1] => IFNULL(P.Partijnaam
    [2] =>  'Leeg gemeld') AS Partijnaam
    [3] => R.Ras
    [4] => M.Maat
    [5] => DATE_FORMAT(KS.Timestamp
    [6] =>  '%d-%c-%Y') AS Datum
    [7] => H.Handelshuis
    [8] => KS.Actie
)
```

But I'm looking for an output like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => K.VisueelNr
    [1] => IFNULL(P.Partijnaam, 'Leeg gemeld') AS Partijnaam
    [2] => R.Ras
    [3] => M.Maat
    [4] => DATE_FORMAT(KS.Timestamp, '%d-%c-%Y') AS Datum
    [5] => H.Handelshuis
    [6] => KS.Actie
)
```

[Here's an PHP Sandbox fiddle to play around](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fc7d6a2e921016e39be8c1be881eae5516976967)

Maybe it has to be done with [preg_split](http://php.net/preg_split), but I don't know how the `regex` would look like then...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `preg_split` which splits the input according to the given regex.

```
$words = preg_split('~,(?![^()]*\))~', $str);
print_r($words);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qV3lS6/1)

Explanation:

- `,` matches all the commas, only if it's not
- followed by any char but not of `(` or `)`, zero or more times
- and further followed by a closing bracket.

If you change `(?!` to `(?=`, it does the opposite of matching all the commas which are present inside the brackets.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its works indeed as expected. And thank you very much for the demo link also. The information provided by the explanation is very helpfull

Comment: @Mathlight Note that this method is very fragile. It breaks when there are nested function calls.

Comment: @nhahtdh luckily that's not the case. But now I'm curious. Can you point me to somewhere with an explanation for this problem?

Comment: @Mathlight: Here is an example `func(arg1, func(arg2)) as field`. You can't expect it to work correctly in general when you only look at some characters in front of a `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Needed a solution that works with nested brackets and came up with this:

```
$delimiter = ',';
$string = "K.VisueelNr,IFNULL(P.Partijnaam, 'Leeg gemeld') AS Partijnaam,func(arg1, func(arg2)) as field";

$array = explode($delimiter, $string);
$new_array = [];
$helper_string = '';
$count1 = 0;
$count2 = 0;
foreach ($array as $str) {
    $count1 += substr_count($str, '(');
    $count2 += substr_count($str, ')');
    if (strlen($helper_string) > 0) {
        $helper_string .= $delimiter;
    }
    $helper_string .= $str;
    if ($count1 === $count2) {
        $new_array[] = $helper_string;
        $helper_string = '';
        $count1 = 0;
        $count2 = 0;
    }
}
// Fallback in case of broken brackets
if (strlen($helper_string)) {
    $new_array[] = $helper_string;
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => K.VisueelNr
    [1] => IFNULL(P.Partijnaam, 'Leeg gemeld') AS Partijnaam
    [2] => func(arg1, func(arg2)) as field
)
```